# Login not successful when spring security is added in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

[image]My project was running fine, but when I added spring security dependency in pom.xml as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I got the login screen ,no matter which URL I typed. But when I tried to login using default username:user and password generated by spring security, I got the following error:

> org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException:
>   The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially
>   malicious String "//"     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:345)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:313)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
>
> 2019-07-26 15:15:06.963  WARN 8796 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom
>   instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [298]
>   milliseconds. 2019-07-26 15:16:46.538 ERROR 8796 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>
> org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException:
>   The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially
>   malicious String "//"     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:345)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:313)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
>
> 2019-07-26 15:16:47.835 ERROR 8796 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>
> org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException:
>   The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially
>   malicious String "//"     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:345)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:313)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ashwin.rws</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restful-web-services</name>
    <description>Restful web services</description>

    <properties>
         <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String `"//"` at, there might be one extra `/`

Comment: yes that was one extra "/" error. But howeever I tried to login by default username and password it is showing me bad credintals.(see the image above,I edited the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//" at, there might be one extra /

Add this and try to login with username and password as root

*application-properties.*

```
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=root
```